# jenkins job builder - Multiple regex job filters when creating a list view

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-job-builder

I am attempting to create a view through jjb that uses two regex job filters. regex-job is a dict but I am unable to get the syntax down. So far have tried things like

```
- view:
    name: 'viewname'
    view-type: 'list'
    regex: 'regexfromoutsidejobfilterblock'
    job-filters:
      - regex-job:
          - regex: 'regex1'
            match-type: 'excludeMatched'
            regex-name: 'one'
          - regex: 'regex2'
            match-type: 'includeMatched'
            regex-name: 'two'
      - job-status:
          disabled: true
          match-type: 'excludeMatched'
```

which returns a broken xml

```
 + <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 + <hudson.model.ListView>
 +   <name>viewname</name>
 +   <description>&lt;!-- Managed by Jenkins Job Builder --&gt;</description>
 +   <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
 +   <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
 +   <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
 +   <jobNames>
 +     <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
 +   </jobNames>
 +   <jobFilters/>
 +   <columns>
 +     <hudson.views.StatusColumn/>
 +     <hudson.views.WeatherColumn/>
 +     <hudson.views.JobColumn/>
 +     <hudson.views.LastSuccessColumn/>
 +     <hudson.views.LastFailureColumn/>
 +     <hudson.views.LastDurationColumn/>
 +     <hudson.views.BuildButtonColumn/>
 +   </columns>
 +   <includeRegex>regexfromoutsidejobfilterblock</includeRegex>
 +   <recurse>false</recurse>
 + </hudson.model.ListView>
```

and something like

```
job-filters:
      regex-job:
          regex: 'regex1'
          regex-name: 'one'
          match-type: 'excludeMatched'
      regex-job:
          regex: 'regex2'
          regex-name: 'two'
          match-type: 'includeMatched'
      job-status:
          disabled: true
          match-type: 'excludeMatched'
```

simply used the second regex to overwrite the first.

Thank you in advance